# App APK seems different on Amazon App Store

Tags: android, apk, proguard, amazon-appstore

The APK seems fine on my end, but then after it goes through it displays a message I created that means there is no internet connection. Note: it is zip aligned and has proguard. Has anyone had similar issues? If so, how did you get past this? By the way, basically the same APK (different package name, etc.) is on the play store and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Just as I suspected: I disabled proguard and resent the APK.  It seems fine now. I am not sure what Amazon is doing to the APK files I submitted, but Amazon seems to not be putting them back together correctly.